# Cross product for bar resolutions of group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and let $H^*(G,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(H,\mathbb{Z})$ be the respective group cohomology. Let $P \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ and $Q \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be free resolutions of $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}G$ and $\mathbb{Z}H$ modules respectively.

Then we can define a product as follows. Define
$$
  \mu : \text{Hom}_G(P,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes \text{Hom}_H(Q,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_{G \times H}(P \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} Q, \mathbb{Z})
$$
by mapping $f \otimes f'$ to $x \otimes x' \mapsto f(x)f'(x')$ for $x \in P_p$ and $x' \in Q_q$. Then we define the cross product $\times : H^p(G,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^q(H,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^{p+q}(G \times H, \mathbb{Z})$ as the composition of
$$
  H^p(G,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^q(H,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^{p+q}[\text{Hom}_G(P,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes \text{Hom}_H(Q,\mathbb{Z})]
$$
with
$$
  \mu : H^{p+q}[\text{Hom}_G(P,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes \text{Hom}_H(Q,\mathbb{Z})] \rightarrow H^{p+q}(\text{Hom}_{G \times H}(P \otimes Q, \mathbb{Z})) = H^{p+q}(G \times H,\mathbb{Z})
$$

Does anybody know what cross product becomes in terms of the bar resolution, i.e where we have that cochains are functions from $G^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$? Is there a nice explicit description is this case?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Try looking in "Cohomology of number fields" by Neukirch. I think it might have what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, unfortunately I couldn't find in Neukirch, defines the cup product but as far as I can see there is no definition of the crossed product. (Maybe I didn't check carefully enough though)